# Updating Live Tile in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

I am trying to build a custom calender app for windows phone 8.1 and I want to show current day and date on app tiles.I am trying to update tiles of my Windows Phone 8.1 app in Start Screen using following code

```
 XmlDocument tileXml2 = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150PeekImageAndText01);
        var textElement2 = tileXml2.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].AppendChild(tileXml2.CreateTextNode("some text"));

        var tileImage = tileXml2.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as XmlElement;
        tileImage.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/WideLogo.png");


        var tn2 = new TileNotification(tileXml2);
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tn2);


        XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Block);
        var textElement = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode("01"));
        textElement = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1].AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode("Tue"));
        var tn = new TileNotification(tileXml);
        //.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().
        //TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().StartPeriodicUpdate()
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication("App").Clear();
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication("App").Update(tn);
```

But when I run the code, TileSquare150x150Block is only updated whereas while changing the tile size, TileWide310x150PeekImageAndText01 is not updated.

Can you please help me on updating multiple tiles? Also how can I get current date on app tiles?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Because you invoke TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication("App").Clear() after registration of TileWide310x150PeekImageAndText01. So, all updates are removed.